# Conditional probability of Poisson given $Y_1 + Y_2 = m$

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions, poisson-distribution

I had a probability question I was hoping for some help on! First, the question:

> Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent Poisson random variables with means $λ_1$ and $λ_2$, respectively.
>
> > a) Find the probability density function of $Y_1 + Y_2$.
> >
> > b)Find the conditional probability density function of $Y_1$, given that $Y_1 + Y_2 = m$

By doing the method of using moment generating functions, I was able to find a) such that:

$M_{y1} (t) = e^{λ(e^t -1)}$

$U=Y_1+Y_2$

$M_u(t) = M_{y1}(t) * M_{y2}(t)$

$M_u(t) = e^{λ_1(e^t -1)} * e^{λ_2(e^t -1)}$ = $e^{(λ_1+λ_2)(e^t-1)}$

Thus, $U= Y_1 + Y_2$ follows Poisson with mean ($λ_1 + λ_2$); Thus giving the probability density function $p(y) = \dfrac{λ^ye^{-λ}}{y!}$

However, b) is much trickier. I know that the conditional function is

$P(Y_1|Y_1 + Y_2 = m) = \dfrac{P(Y1,Y1+Y2 = m)}{P(Y1+Y2 = m)}$ = $\dfrac{P(Y1)*P(Y1+Y2 = m)}{P(Y1+Y2 = m)}$

because of the independence of the variables. However, I'm not sure how to solve this because if it is so, wouldn't the $P(Y_1+Y_2 = m)$ 's just cancel? Would someone be able to help me? Thank you so much in advanced, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write in your solution to b) does not make sense ($P(Y_1)$ is undefined, as $Y_1$ is a random variable, not an event). The probability density function of $(Y_1\mid Y_1+Y_2=m)$ is by definition
$$
P(Y_1=k\mid Y_1+Y_2=m),\quad k\ge0.
$$
This is zero if $k>m$ and if $k\le m$, by Bayes' theorem,
\begin{align*}
P(Y_1=k\mid Y_1+Y_2=m)
=\frac{P(Y_1=k,Y_1+Y_2=m)}{P(Y_1+Y_2=m)}
&=\frac{P(Y_1=k,Y_2=m-k)}{P(Y_1+Y_2=m)}\\
&=\frac{P(Y_1=k)\,P(Y_2=m-k)}{P(Y_1+Y_2=m)},
\end{align*}
by independence of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.
At this point, you should be able to finish the computation since you know the pdf of $Y_1$, $Y_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$.

Comment: So Y2 = m - k because of Bayes' theorem?

Comment: No, $\{Y_1=k\text{ and }Y_1+Y_2=m\}=\{Y_1=k\text{ and }k+Y_2=m\}=\{Y_1=k\text{ and }Y_2=m-k\}$ as events.

Comment: Following the logic of the numerator, why wouldn't the denominator be $P(Y_2 = m-k)$ as well?

Comment: @BillyThorton, in the numerator the set is $\{\mathbf{Y_1=k\text{ and }}Y_1+Y_2=m\}$, which explains why one may replace $Y_1$ by $k$. Why would you replace $Y_1$ by $k$ in the denominator?

Comment: So essentially the event(s) and their associate sets in the numerator are separate from the events in the denominator?

Comment: @BillyThorton, yes indeed. Bayes' theorem states that the conditional probability is the ratio of the probabilities of two (distinct) events. The event in the numerator has nothing to do with the event in the denominator.